# button disappears in a horizontal orientation

Tags: android, button

Hello I have LinearLayout in ScrollView
In this LinearLayout I have some checkbox and
button at the bottom.
In vertical view it's ok but in horizontal view 
the button disappear.

You can see this situation on screen shots:

**vertical view**

[image]

**horizontal view**

[image]

Of course srclolling down doesnt help

This is my xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >


    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/hotele"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hotele"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:checked="true"
        />

     <!-- more checkboxs... -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gotowe"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Gotowe"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried scrolling down?

Comment: of course im not an idiot :)

Comment: Your first linearlayout needs to be wrap_content for height.

Comment: Done.. but doesnt't help

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

to be with `layout_height="wrap_content"` . This will let you scroll to the end of the content.

Comment: try then to set `android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"` to the RelativeLayout that is wrapping the button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your looking for but may this help you

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="9.5">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/hotele"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Hotele"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gotowe"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Gotowe"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        >


        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/hotele"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hotele"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:checked="true"
            />

        <!-- more checkboxs... -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotowe"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Gotowe"

        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this make the button on the center of screen and scroll doesn't scroll any more

Comment: change the position of button it is in relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >


    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/hotele"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hotele"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:checked="true"
        />

     <!-- more checkboxs... -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gotowe"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Gotowe"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : The list of checkbox will be scrollable and the button will be shown in two cases : 
 (As for the margin is up to you to choose the values of your margins)

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollable_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gotowe"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/hotele"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Hotele"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                />
            <!-- more checkboxs... -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotowe"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Gotowe"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want to place the button on the left ?  
If you want to place the button on the left ==>  remove **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** and add **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"**

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change from your current xml file.
Try changing the margins of your inner Linearlayout to padding.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="80dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        >
```

I was able to make it work this way.